# Opening shell files via Terminal (default application)

Tags: command-line

Currently in Ubuntu 16.04 and can't open Shell files with terminal (as the default program). I can make them run normally with sh after directing to the directory; however always used to be able to "Execute in terminal".
Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, there are a few things to check :

Make sure you are running your shell file on a way that lets understand to your terminal that it is a file that is stored in the current folder. For instance, if the filename of your script is myscript.sh, **do not type** `myscript.sh` **but** `./myscript.sh`. If you don't, the terminal would think that the script is in an other place, such as

```
/bin/
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

the most of the time, concerning installed or system commands. The dot refers to current folder, whereas two dots (`..`) refer to parent folder.

The other point you can check, is that you have the permission to execute the file. If you are running Ubuntu, right click on your file -> properties -> permissions -> check "Allow execution as a programm".

I'm not sure, but you may also need to begin you script with following line : `#!/bin/sh`, altough I've already used script without such a header line.